# How to add a second table automatically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

What I am trying to do is create a admin page the I can use edit a table using Javascript. What this is for are live results for tractor pulling to post to our website. All I need is to be able to post the driver, vehicle, distance, and it automatically sort by distance. Currently I am able to do all this for one table, but I want to add a second table for another class. I don't know if this is possible or not. I thought about trying to call another table from a different html file, but don't know how to display both the tables from two different html files together. Any assistance is appreciated. I have some Javascript experience, but not as much as needed for this project.

I have tried to update two different html files which works, but can't get them on the same html page as if it were on our website.

I should be able to be on the admin page, type in the driver's details, click new row for next puller, save it and so on. Once done with the class, click new class (new table) and do it all over again. Once done I want to be able to publish it, but clear everything to be ready for the next event.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Results</title>
<style>
 
 table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
 }
 
 th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
 }
 
 table tr{
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
 }
 
 tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #f2f2f2
 }
 
 table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
 }
 
</style>
</head>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <th colspan="3"><h1 align="center">Medford, WI</h1></th>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3"><h2 align="center">Light Super Stock Tractors</h2></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Driver</th>
    <th>Vehicle</th>
    <th>Distance</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</html>
```

```css
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['myTable']))
        die('No data provided.');

    $table = $_POST['myTable'];

    $handle = fopen('myTable.html','w');
    $result = fwrite($handle,$table);
    if($result)
        fclose($handle);
    else
        die('Error writing file');
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery AJAX</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    tr, td,th{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border:1px solid;
    }
    td{
        height:22px;
        min-width:125px;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">"http://jquery.com"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        var getTable = function () {
            /*We empty the div */
            $('#myTable').html('');
            /*We load the table */
            $.get('myTable.html', function (callback_data) {
                var table = callback_data;
                document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = table;
            });
        };
        getTable();

        /* ----- */

        /* New row button */
        $('#addRow').click(function (event) {
            /* Prevents the real anchor click event  (going to href link)*/
            event.preventDefault();

            /* We get the number of columns  in a row*/
            var colNumber = $($('#myTable tbody tr')[0]).children('td').length;

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            $('#myTable tbody').append(tr);
        });

        $('#addColumn').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.each($('#myTable table thead tr'), function () {
                $(this).append('<th></th>');
            })
            $.each($('#myTable table tbody tr'), function () {
                $(this).append('<td></td>');
            });
        });

        $('#saveTable').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var table = $('#myTable').html();
            $.post('saveTable.php', {
                'myTable': table
            }, function (callback_data) {
                console.log(callback_data);
                $('#myTable').slideToggle('fast');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getTable();
                    $('#myTable').slideToggle();
                }, 100);

            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        var getTable = function () {
            /*We empty the div */
            $('#myTable2').html('');
            /*We load the table */
            $.get('myTable2.html', function (callback_data) {
                var table = callback_data;
                document.getElementById('myTable2').innerHTML = table;
            });
        };
        getTable();

        /* ----- */

        /* New row button */
        $('#addRow2').click(function (event) {
            /* Prevents the real anchor click event  (going to href link)*/
            event.preventDefault();

            /* We get the number of columns  in a row*/
            var colNumber = $($('#myTable2 tbody tr')[0]).children('td').length;

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            $('#myTable2 tbody').append(tr);
        });
     
  $('#addHeader2').click(function (event) {
            /* Prevents the real anchor click event  (going to href link)*/
            event.preventDefault();

            /* We get the number of columns  in a row*/
            var colNumber = $($('#myTable2 tbody tr')[0]).children('td').length;

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            $('#myTable2 tbody').append(tr);
        });

        $('#addColumn2').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.each($('#myTable2 table thead tr'), function () {
                $(this).append('<th></th>');
            })
            $.each($('#myTable2 table tbody tr'), function () {
                $(this).append('<td></td>');
            });
        });

        $('#saveTable2').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var table = $('#myTable2').html();
            $.post('saveTable.php', {
                'myTable': table
            }, function (callback_data) {
                console.log(callback_data);
                $('#myTable2').slideToggle('fast');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getTable();
                    $('#myTable2').slideToggle();
                }, 100);

            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Live Results Admin Page</h1>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div id="myTable" contenteditable></div>
            <nav data-type="table-tools">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="addRow">New row</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="addColumn">New column</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="saveTable">Save table</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div id="myTable2" contenteditable></div>
            <nav data-type="table-tools">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="addRow2">New row</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="addColumn2">New column</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="saveTable2">Save table</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is currently too unspecific and broad.

Comment: Why aren't you just storing the data in a database? Then you can set what class each entry belongs to and you can fetch and sort the results how ever you want?

Comment: Magnus, I have thought about doing that, but never really touched much with databases. Do you have any resources you could point me to that would help me with getting this to work?

Comment: Just google for "Getting started with PHP and MySQL" and you will get _many_ hits with tutorials/guides. Just make sure that the tutorials are relatively new (and aren't using the old `mysql_*` api) and are using prepared statements.

Comment: I'll start there and see how far I can get myself. Thank you for pointing me into a direction to get me started.

Comment: I would suggest putting both tables in the html then control the visibility of the tables according to your needs using scripts.